# How Can I Create a Custom Kentico Module from an Angular Application?

Tags: angular, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, kentico, kentico-12

I have a requirement to build a custom Kentico Module for a client, but I don't want to use the clunky, built-in Kentico framework. There's a lot of things that Kentico does right, but custom modules are not (in my opinion) one of them.

I'd like to use an embedded Angular app, but I don't see any documentation to explain how.

Comment: did you ever find a resolution for this question? Did any of the answers below help? We're trying (hoping) to find a way to integrate Kentico and Angular and looking for examples - the data is easy to get, but structuring a page is proving more problematic

Comment: Yes I did, in fact I've been doing a lot of it ever since. Happy to help if you're still looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are really a lot of options to achieve what you need.

Kentico is ASP.NET web site or web app (depending on your particular installation), so you could implement web api end point(s) to serve UI or simply use Kentico [REST API](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service).

Also solution would be different is you just want to add it on the live site page, or substitute Kentico native user interface for modules.

Anyway you'll need to create module along with its classes through Kentico, save generated classes (Info and Provider) and the rest is up to you. Again this is just asp.net app and you're free to use any approach that works better for you.

At the end I personally like custom modules as they allow to build CRUD interface for class' family fairly easily and quickly as well as provides a lot of options for extension, but that's just my preference.